# Matching Date formatted: "January 17, 2017 10:30 AM" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date, datetime

I have been trying to use Date/DateTime to validate that a given date is in the correct format.

```
str = "January 17, 2017 10:30 AM"
temp = DateTime.strptime(str, '%B %-d, %y %l:%M %p')
```

but am getting the error

```
`strptime': invalid date (ArgumentError)
```

I have been able to split the string into ""January 17," "2017 10:30 AM" and validate it without issue, but I would really like to know why I can't just use strptime on the whole string, or what I am doing wrong if it can be done.

Comment: You can use `DateTime.parse` if the string doesn't need to be in that exact format, i.e. to allow valid date strings formatted differently.

Comment: To be fair, I'll mention that Cody had a working and well documented answer a few seconds before me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format works fine :

```
temp = DateTime.strptime(str, '%B %d, %Y %l:%M %p')
#<DateTime: 2017-01-17T10:30:00+00:00 ((2457771j,37800s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: the only difference is %d instead of ‰-d ?

Comment: And Y for 4 digit year

Answer (score 2):

This error is happening because according to the docs of `DateTime#strptime`:

> Parses the given representation of date and time with the given template, and creates a date object. strptime does not support specification of flags and width unlike strftime.

And your format includes a value of `%-d` which is a width parameter, hence the exception. If you try a basic invocation like:

`DateTime.strptime(str, '%B %d, %Y')`

you'll see it works. Also, you'll want uppercase-Y for the full 4-digit year.

In a nutshell: you'll need to adjust your format string